# SELECT MAX Date T-SQL Subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery

I am attempting to SELECT rows from a table using a query like this

```
SELECT     pminf_member, pminf_schmem
         , pminf_date, pminf_fund
         , pminf_cont, pminf_rate
         , pminf_matrix
FROM   pe_minvf
WHERE (pminf_member = 4380) 
  AND (pminf_schmem = 'M') 
  AND (pminf_date <= '03/30/2011')
  AND (pminf_date =
           (SELECT MAX(pminf_date) AS Expr1
            FROM   pe_minvf AS pe_minvf_1
            WHERE  (pminf_member = 4380)
           )
       )
  AND (pminf_fund = 'LIFESTYLE')
```

What I should be getting from my subquery (I think) is a date of '01/01/2011' but when I run my query I am getting no results back.

If I replace the subquery with the hardcoded date I get the correct rows returned. For example

```
SELECT  pminf_member, pminf_schmem
      , pminf_date, pminf_fund
      , pminf_cont, pminf_rate
      , pminf_matrix
FROM  pe_minvf
WHERE (pminf_member = 4380)
  AND (pminf_schmem = 'M')
  AND (pminf_date <= '03/30/2011')
  AND (pminf_date = '01/01/2011')
  AND (pminf_fund = 'LIFESTYLE')
```

This query returns the correct results.

Any ideas why the subquery is not returning the max date or if it is, why am I getting no rows back?

Thanks,
Tristan

Comment: What do you get it you run the subquery alone?

Comment: I do not understand these conditions:  ... AND (pminf_date <= '03/30/2011') AND (pminf_date = '01/01/2011')  -- NEVER MIND -- but I cannot delete this comment. SO won't let me.

Comment: I get the correct date returned if I run the subquery on its own.

Comment: What is the datatype of pminf_date? Is it a date or a datetime?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You filter on different conditions in your queries.

It's `pminf_fund = 'LIFESTYLE'` in the subquery but `pminf_schmem = 'M'` in the outer query.

Also, you limit the date in the outer query and don't do it in the subquery.

If you just need the most recent record up to '03/30/2011', use this:

```
SELECT  TOP 1
        pminf_member, pminf_schmem, pminf_date, pminf_fund, pminf_cont, pminf_rate, pminf_matrix
FROM    pe_minvf
WHERE   pminf_member = 4380
        AND pminf_schmem = 'M'
        AND pminf_fund = 'LIFESTYLE'
        AND pminf_date <= '03/30/2011'
ORDER BY
        pminf_date DESC
```

Comment: Unfortunately I dont need the most recent record. I need to date of the most recent contribution no matter if it is of a 'LIFESTYLE' type or not. I need to see if the current fund in effect is 'LIFESTYLE' or not..

Comment: Yeah, there can be multiple types for that field but I only want results returned if the pminf_field = 'M' but I don't want that to be the case when Selecting the most recent date..

Comment: @TGuimond: if the most recent record is not `LIFESTYLE`, do you want it to be returned or not? Also, do you want it to be returned if it's later than `'03/30/2001'`?

Comment: The `pminf_fund = 'LIFESTYLE'` is not in the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT     pminf_member, pminf_schmem
         , pminf_date, pminf_fund
         , pminf_cont, pminf_rate
         , pminf_matrix
FROM   pe_minvf 
WHERE (pminf_member = 4380) 
  AND (pminf_schmem = 'M') 
  AND (pminf_date =
           (SELECT MAX(pminf_date) AS Expr1
            FROM   pe_minvf AS p
            WHERE  (p.pminf_member = 4380) AND 
                   p.pminf_date <= '03/30/2011'
           )
       )
  AND (pminf_fund = 'LIFESTYLE')
```

Answer (score 0):

The query:

```
SELECT MAX(pminf_date) AS Expr
FROM   pe_minvf AS pe_minvf_1
WHERE  (pminf_member = 4380)
;
```

returns `'01/01/2011'` or something else?

Perhaps you want the same conditions on the subquery as in th emain query:

```
SELECT MAX(pminf_date) AS Expr
FROM   pe_minvf AS pe_minvf_1
WHERE  (pminf_member = 4380)
  AND  (pminf_schmem = 'M')
```

Answer (score 0):

use a subquery to limit rows returned instead of the where clause.  Use this as the subquery:

```
(SELECT MAX(pminf_date) AS Expr1             
FROM   pe_minvf AS pe_minvf_1             
WHERE  (pminf_member = 4380)
```

Keep the query basically the same...

```
Select same_fields_as you_did_before
from pe_minvf
inner join 
 (SELECT MAX(pminf_date) AS Maxdate, tablekey             
 FROM   pe_minvf AS pe_minvf_1             
 WHERE  pminf_member = 4380) a on a.tablekey = pe_minvf.table_key
where same_where_clause_you_had
```

Make sense?  I wasn't sure what your table_key was on pe_minvf...you'll have to insert that yourself.  I find using subqueires adn inner joining to them is a more effective way of limiting rows then having a subquery in your where clause

Answer (score 0):

Twelfth! 
Thanks for the proper syntax... I used it to resolve my similar problem de-jur (of-the-day)
Unless I am wrong, what I have below will work.. If it doesn't I will fix it here...
In the example below the data fields name have been cleansed but the syntax worked very fast.
By the way, there are 20,480 distinct device_id

```
declare 
 @BegDate varchar(20)=(select cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), getdate()-2,101) as varchar(20)) + ' 10:59:59 PM')
,@EndDate varchar(20)=(select cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), getdate()-0,101) as varchar(20)) + ' 11:00:00 PM')
  select f1.ABC_ConfigProcStatusID,f1.DeviceID,f1.DBfilename ,f1.LastUpdatedDate
    from dbo.ABC_ConfigProcStatus f1
        inner join
          (select distinct DeviceID,max(LastUpdatedDate) as max_DeviceIDdte
            from dbo.ABC_ConfigProcStatus 
            where [Status]=2  
            and DeviceID not in(select ExclusionDeviceIDs from ABC_ConfigDeviceIDExclusionList)
            group by DeviceID) f2 
        on f2.max_DeviceIDdte = f1.LastUpdatedDate
   where [Status]=2  
   and f2.DeviceID = f1.DeviceID
   and f1.DeviceID not in(select ExclusionDeviceIDs from ABC_ConfigDeviceIDExclusionList)
   and LastUpdatedDate between @BegDate and @EndDate
   and left(upper(f1.DeviceID),3) in ('XYZ','ZKO')
   order by f1.LastUpdatedDate
```

Comment: Sorry, I could not get the post to retain the proper format. HF.